# Unable to install VS2012 VSIX after upgrading for VS2013

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, vsix

So I have followed the steps detailed in the following link to upgrade my VSIX installer for VS2013

http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2013/06/27/upgrading-vsix-extensions-from-vs2012-to-vs2013.aspx

but even though I have VS2012 and VS2013 Premium editions I get the below error in the Log which seems to imply that it thinks vs2013 is not installed which is bizarre.

09/01/2014 12:00:05 - Microsoft VSIX Installer
09/01/2014 12:00:05 - -------------------------------------------
09/01/2014 12:00:05 - Initializing Install...
09/01/2014 12:00:06 - Extension Details...
09/01/2014 12:00:06 -   Identifier      : TFS.CheckinPolicy.Installer.Microsoft.4ce2e9b7-2bde-40e7-9140-6ec700499de7
09/01/2014 12:00:06 -   Name            : TFS.CheckinPolicy.Installer
09/01/2014 12:00:06 -   Author          : Microsoft
09/01/2014 12:00:06 -   Version         : 1.0
09/01/2014 12:00:06 -   Description     : Empty VSIX Project.
09/01/2014 12:00:06 -   Locale          : en-US
09/01/2014 12:00:06 -   MoreInfoURL     : 
09/01/2014 12:00:06 -   InstalledByMSI  : False
09/01/2014 12:00:06 -   SupportedFrameworkVersionRange : 4.5
09/01/2014 12:00:06 - 
09/01/2014 12:00:06 -   Supported Products : 
09/01/2014 12:00:06 -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro
09/01/2014 12:00:06 -           Version : 12.0
09/01/2014 12:00:06 -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.Premium
09/01/2014 12:00:06 -           Version : 12.0
09/01/2014 12:00:06 - 
09/01/2014 12:00:06 -   References      : 
09/01/2014 12:00:06 - 
09/01/2014 12:00:06 - Searching for applicable products...
**09/01/2014 12:00:06 - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio Premium 2012

09/01/2014 12:00:06 - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2012

09/01/2014 12:00:06 - Found installed product - Microsoft LightSwitch for Visual Studio 2012

09/01/2014 12:00:06 - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Shell (Integrated)

09/01/2014 12:00:06 - Found installed product - Global Location

09/01/2014 12:00:06 - VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.

   at VSIXInstaller.App.InitializeInstall()

   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()

   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()**

Any ideas as to why this may be happening?